# SVG not rendering on live Chrome page

Tags: html, svg

Despite a few various solutions, my SVG is still not properly appearing on my website when it's published live. It works perfectly on my local server and computer, but as soon as I publish the site, the svg no longer appears. The HTML for my svg is using an img tag wrapped in an a tag for functionality

```
<a href="index.html" id="owi-logo"><img src="img/logos/owi-logo.svg" alt="owi logo"></a>
```

And my SVG file referenced starts with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 244 64.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 244 64.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#666668;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<title>Asset 3</title>
<path class="st0" d="M220.9,32.3 ........ (cont)
```

full SVG file [here](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/abzbVJy)

However, when I run this on my local computer, I get this image (this is good):

[image: how i want the image to be]

Yet when I publish my page, I get the following (not good):

[image: not what I want]

Am I doing something incorrectly with the svg version or perhaps using the incorrect tags on my page that's making this not work live?

I have reviewed all my directories and am sure that the HTML file paths are correct.

This svg works fine in the footer, but not in the header. I am using the same html, just without the a tags. `<img src="img/logos/OWI-LOGO.svg" alt="overlandwest logo" />`.

Comment: where is the end tag for <path class="st0" d="M220.9,32.3

Comment: The svg file is very long, so I didn't include the entirety. Here it is on Codepen : https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/abzbVJy . It works fine in almost every instance, except when i publish the page live

Comment: It has to be your file path or URI. Check that your file paths have the same letter case with your reference. for example (img is not Img) etc.

Comment: thank you both for your help. I found the issue was related to the fact that I had another instance of the same SVG file on the page (I didn't know you couldn't use more than one instance of the same SVG on a page at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help to those that did. The error turned out to be the fact that the SVG was being used in more than one instance on the page. I made a copy of the SVG at hand, renamed it, and then used this in the header and it's now working properly.

The html page chose to use the svg on the bottom, but not the top of the page, and this wasn't working while the site was published live.